# How can i create a new set of columns to my code below instead of row?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a information site for my coworkers where they can add all the info they have so they don't need to write it down. The variable $cam_loc displays the location of certain equipment. When i use the code below instead of using one panel title per location it duplicates the location if there is more than 1 equipment in that place. I would like to make a conditional that verifies if the location is duplicated and if so instead of adding another panel-title it should add another column with the second pair of information in that location.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$cam = $db->prepare('select * from camere');
$cam->execute();

while ($cams = $cam->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {?>
  <ul class="list" style="list-style: none;">                                                                               
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <li><h3 class="panel-title"><?php $cam_loc = $cams->locatie; ?><?php echo $cam_loc;?></h3> </li>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2" align="center">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a class="list-group-item">Model: <strong><?php echo $cams->model; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Ip Intern: <strong><?php echo $cams->ip_int; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Ip Extern: <strong><?php echo $cams->ip_ext; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Port: <strong><?php echo $cams->port; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">User: <strong><?php echo $cams->user; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Pass: <strong><?php echo $cams->pass; ?></strong></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>          
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like something that should be done from the database, can you `SELECT * FROM camere ORDER BY some_location_field`?

Comment: Well that will not help since 'locatie' is placed 2 times in the 'camere' table and when I display it its the same. Probably I need to read up on relational databases. Thought there is a js trick to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you'd need to sort your results by title in your SQL statement which will group them together, then use an `if` statement to work out if the current record has the same title as the previous one.

```
<?php
$cam = $db->prepare('select * from camere');
$cam->execute();

$heading = "";

while ($cams = $cam->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {?>
  <ul class="list" style="list-style: none;">                                                                               
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

      <?php $cam_loc = $cams->locatie;

      if ($heading != $cam_loc) { ?>

      <div class="panel-heading">
        <li><h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $cam_loc; ?></h3> </li>
      </div>

      <?php }
          //Update $heading ready for the next row.
          $heading = $cam_loc;
      } ?>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2" align="center">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a class="list-group-item">Model: <strong><?php echo $cams->model; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Ip Intern: <strong><?php echo $cams->ip_int; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Ip Extern: <strong><?php echo $cams->ip_ext; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Port: <strong><?php echo $cams->port; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">User: <strong><?php echo $cams->user; ?></strong></a>
              <a class="list-group-item">Pass: <strong><?php echo $cams->pass; ?></strong></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>          
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

You may have to move some of your HTML tags around a bit within those new code lines to give you the desired layout you require but as it is above you won't get a new heading for every record.

Comment: The ideea is good but the last 3 divs remain unclosed and each panel goes into the last one.